# what's the difference between function calls?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

What's the main difference? I'm a newbie, just started the generics. Two methods are doing the same thing. I've heard about casting but not sure how it works here.

```
public interface IA
{
}

public struct A : IA
{
}

public static void Test1(IA obj)
{
}

public static void Test2<T>(T obj) where T : IA
{
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A();
        
    Test1(a);
    Test2(a);
}
```

All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods accept an IA, but the generic one has knowledge of the real object being passed.

Consider what would happen if you return obj from your function:

```
public static IA Test1(IA obj)
{
    return obj;
}

public static T Test2<T>(T obj) where T : IA
{
    return obj
}
```

The non generic can only ever return an IA interface, because that's all it gets.

The generic on the other hand can return a concrete object, and effectively becomes a different method for every different type of object that it gets called with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B(); //also implements IA
    
    IA ret1 = Test1(a); // this can only return an IA
    A ret2A = Test2(a); // this returns an A 
    B ret2B = Test2(b); // this returns a B! It's effectively a different function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `A` is a struct, passing `a` to `Test1(IA)` causes the value to be [boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#boxing), because interfaces ae reference types.

Passing it to `Test2<T>(T)` does not require boxing, because `T` can be inferred as `A`, so the method is effectively `Test2(A)` at compile time.

However, because, `Test2<T>(T)` is constrained to be an `IA`, public members defined on that interface will still be accessible within the method.